# View path variable

Tags: views

How can I programmatically fetch the view path field value?

[image]

I am able to fetch title and body, but but I cannot get the path.

```
function view_path_views_pre_render(\Drupal\views\ViewExecutable $view) {
  kint($view->result);
  if ($view->id() == 'view_idea_shots_for_home_page' && $view->current_display == 'block_3') {
    foreach ($view->result as $value) {
      kint($value->_entity->get('title')->value);
      kint($value->_entity->get('body')->value);
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: Did you try `$value->_entity->get('path')->value` ?

Comment: Yes iam getting null

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`path` is not a field stored in the entity. It is a computed views field plugin, which can only be outputted by applying [Path::render()](https://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/core%21modules%21node%21src%21Plugin%21views%21field%21Path.php/function/Path%3A%3Arender/8.4.x):

```
$path = $view->field['path']->render($value);
```